# With Excel VBA, how can I snap an Option Button on a sheet to a specific range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of radio buttons (form option buttons, not activex) on a sheet. I am running into a problem where when I email the workbook, the option buttons distort and resize to an unusable size and in different positions. They look fine on my computer though so I don't know what is causing this.

So, I am trying to fix it by snapping the buttons to a cell. I have used this sub to snap it to whichever cell the TopLeft of the button touches. But, what I want to do is snap the button to an exact range, such as Range("C5"). Is it possible to accomplish this?

```
Sub OptionButton_Align()

    With Sheets("Training").OptionButtons("Option Button 1")
        .Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
        .Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
        .Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
        .Height = .TopLeftCell.Height
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Sub OptionButton_Align()
    Dim rCell as Range
    Set rCell = Sheets("Training").Range("C5")
    With Sheets("Training").OptionButtons("Option Button 1")
        .Left = rCell.Left
        .Top = rCell.Top
        .Width = rCell.Width
        .Height = rCell.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That does it. Do you you have any idea why the buttons resize after I email the workbook? They move position slightly and become very slim slivers that you can barely see.

Comment: I've not found it on my files. But I think you can try to change shape setting.  [Shape setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM1PV.png)